# Etherchannel between Cisco Catalyst 3548 and Linux box

Tags: linux, bonding, cisco-catalyst, lacp

We have a Cisco 3548XL switch. 
Fa0/1 and Fa0/2 are configured with the:

```
    port group 1
```

option.

This gives me this:

```
    switch#show etherchannel summary 
    Flags:  d - default     D - down
            I - in use

    Group Ports
    ----- -----
    1     Fa0/1(I) Fa0/2(Id)
```

The trouble is, I am unsure which bonding driver option to use on the linux box.

The linux box is connected to Fa0/1 and Fa0/2 with eth0 and eth1 respectively. The bond is up with 802.3ad (LACP) selected as the driver option.

I am now of the understanding that the version of IOS on the 3500 series of switches doesn't support LACP.

My questions are:

- Does the 3548 switch use PaGP natively
- Should I use a different bonding method on the linux box such as balance-rr (0)
- If I use a bonding method such as balance-tlb (5) that doesn't require any special switch support on the linux box, should I disable Etherchannel on the switch?
- Shall I just find a switch that supports LACP 802.3ad such as a 2950 with IOS12.1 release 22?

On another note, I tried to configure the new port group on this switch using this command:

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You should be using bonding mode - 4.